# Using Docker-compose, how to access the container database via the same port in container and in host

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm running a docker-compose container for postgresql.  The postgresql database in the container is running on the standard port 5432, and I am publishing that port out to port 5444 on the host (since the host's postgresql default port is in use).

I am using the same configuration on the host and in the container (a .env file that provides config settings for cli commands and the app as a whole).  Unfortunately, whichever port I choose, one system will lose access.  For example, I cannot run:

```
[k@host]$ pgsql -p 5444 # Connects
```

in the host and still have work inside the container:

```
[k@db-container]$ pgsql -p 5444 # Errors in container
```

The container's postgresql-server is running on 5432:

```
[k@db-container]$ pgsql -p 5432 # Connects successfully in container
```

and the ports are published via the docker-compose.yml via:
- ports:
  - "5444:5432"

So currently I don't know how to configure the same port everywhere simply via the docker-compose.yml! `expose` command exposes the port but does not allow remapping, `ports` forwards host<-->container, but does not remap the internal port. I have thought of remapping the postgresql default port inside the postgresql container configuration, but fully reconfiguring postgresql seems non-trivial to do via docker-compose on every `docker-compose up`.

How can I remap the ports inside the container so that I can use port 5444 everywhere, in the host & container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard PostgreSQL client library supports [several environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-envars.html) that tell it where the server is.  In the same way that you can configure the host using `$PGHOST`, you can configure the port using `$PGPORT`.

In a Docker Compose context, it should be straightforward to set these:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    ports: ['5444:5432']
    volumes: ['./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data']
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports: ['8888:8888']
    env:
      PGHOST: postgres
      # default PGPORT=5432 will work fine
```

Similarly, if you're running the application in a development environment on the host, you can set

```
PGHOST=localhost PGPORT=5444 ./myapp
```

Comment: That works, I can modify the commands on my local development (by passing ENV vars), I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same port on the **host**.

Nothing prevents you to run multiple instances if they has **different** IP-addresses.

```
psql -p 5444
```

Defaults to `psql --host=127.0.0.1 -p 5444`. If you want several instances - obviously you must make them different in some way.